# Grails Mapping Template

Tags: grails, mapping

i want to make grails mapping template.

the example like this.

URL :

```
http://localhost:8080/controller/action/id/
```

i have 2 gsp views

```
1.Product
2.Product_create
```

when variable `id == "create"`

grails automatically display product_create if not grails will display product.

is anyone can solve this??

please correct my english. thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
def product( String id ){
  if( 'create' == id ) return render( view:'product_create' )
  def product = doSomethingWithId()
  [ product:product, ... ] // here the default "product.gsp" will be rendered
}
```

Comment: not like it, the process is not in the controller, but in Grails mapping automatically, does not create a mapping for each controller.

Comment: didn't understand a word.

Comment: i think you answer is right, but i need to make it automaticly, with some routing script